# There's been a kidnapping!

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

Alfred C. Bacon, an avid puzzler, has been kidnapped! Fortunately, we were able to find where he was being held. Unfortunately, he was no longer there. Fortunately, he left us a note, letting us know that he was safe, (although not necessarily happy). Fortunately, he let us know that he had encoded his kidnapper's name in a hidden message. Unfortunately, our intrepid police force has hit a brick wall with how to solve his puzzle. They believe that it's tied to his internet history.

They have sent you, the denizens of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com, the entirety of his browsing history, and are relying on you to figure out who the kidnapper is so that they can once again begin the search for Freddy.

```
twitch.tv                       10/11/17 11:17 PM   50.112.196.159
microsoft.com                   10/10/17 6:30  PM   191.239.213.197
amazon.com                      10/10/17 10:45 AM   54.239.25.192
gizmodo.com                     10/9/17  9:42  AM   151.101.193.34
kickstarter.com                 10/9/17  5:41  AM   13.33.76.156
discord.gg                      10/8/17  6:19  PM   104.16.60.37
lastpass.com                    10/8/17  6:12  PM   88.221.62.48
instagram.com                   10/7/17  9:45  PM   34.195.2.28
open.spotify.com                10/7/17  12:30 PM   104.199.64.136
southwest.com                   10/6/17  9:45  PM   208.94.153.100
imgur.com                       10/6/17  8:16  AM   151.101.36.193
kotaku.com                      10/6/17  8:12  AM   151.101.129.34
monster.com                     10/6/17  8:07  AM   63.121.30.147
ebay.com                        10/6/17  8:03  AM   66.211.162.12
xkcd.com                        10/5/17  4:30  PM   151.101.0.67
msn.com                         10/4/17  11:11 AM   13.82.28.61
walmart.com                     10/4/17  9:17  AM   161.170.248.20
puzzling.stackexchange.com      10/4/17  7:30  AM   151.101.193.69
reddit.com                      10/2/17  8:31  PM   151.101.193.140
bankofamerica.com               10/2/17  4:15  PM   171.159.228.150
wikipedia.org                   10/2/17  12:35 PM   91.198.174.192
buzzfeed.com                    10/2/17  4:26  AM   13.33.76.217
gmail.com                       10/1/17  9:35  PM   216.58.209.110
aol.com                         10/1/17  6:49  PM   207.200.74.55
```

Who kidnapped Mr. Bacon?

HINT:

The police have approached you with a piece of new information! They found a piece of paper stuck to the bottom of the otherwise empty trash bin that looks like this:

> [image: ![a piece of paper]

HINT 2:

It looks like the police were able to successfully recover part of a file from the otherwise empty hard drive! Here's the portion of the file that they recovered:

> _ic__t_rter.co_ _CC

You'll notice

> _ot__u.co_

some of the sites

> _icro_oft.co_  BFEF_C

have letters missing.

> ___.co_   *C*

That's because the police

> pu__li_g._tac_exch__ge.co_  C

Are police, not the FBI. However, they're very sure that what they have is right, and are also sure that it's got SOMETHING to do with the code. They just don't have any idea what.

*As an aside, is it possible to have a block quote with a spoiler? That would have made the answer much easier to type.*

Hint 3:

IP Addresses have been added to the original list. They were divined by the police's voodoo magic, and definitely not from phroureo's spreadsheet where he saved them all. I sure hope there's not typos in the list again, because that would be embarrassing.

---

*Fair warning: this puzzle is VERY enigmatic. Hints will come periodically as necessary, but eventually, it should be solvable. I hope. :P To be honest, I thought about adding even more layers, but in the end decided to save them for the next puzzle.*

Comment: By quickly scanning and clicking edit I can't find anything... I'm surprised. :P

Comment: The idea of a message hidden in a browsing history is sublime, well done!

Comment: I just searched puzzling.stackexchange.com users and couldn't find a suitable one matching Alfred, Freddy, or Bacon

Comment: I haven't user-searched other sites, however. But I'm not sure if that's possible for any of the others.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no meta-gaming involved in this puzzle :( :) It's purely illogical deduction.

Comment: Looks strange that such an _avid puzzler_ only visited https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ one time in 11 days. Did he fake his own kidnapping? haha.

Comment: He cleared his history so it only included the relevant sites for his code ;)

Comment: (Image copied to imgur and posting updated. Anyone with edit privs could have done this, you know ...)

Comment: @Rubio: Yes, but who wants to be accused of tampering with evidence?

Comment: @MOehm Ha! Ok, well played, you got me there :)

Comment: Quick question regarding your update, the piece of paper lists bestbuy on it, but that doesn't appear on the original list. Deliberate?

Comment: Ehhhh... More or less. Consider it flavor. The final answer of the puzzle is based only off of the sites in the list above. (For what it's worth, I did notice that I had the extra as I was copying the notes from my Excel worksheet to paper, but I decided that it didn't hurt anything.) 

tl;dr: ;D

Comment: I'm disappointed my joke answer has been deleted by a moderator. A joke answer can still be an answer, if it's in the spirit of the problem, and who knows maybe the backstory was important to resolving the enigma. There were no other answers for a long time, so my original spin on the story helped keep the puzzle alive. As it turns out, the questioner clarified that there wasn't any meta-reasoning involved. But my approach was a conceivable if jokey one, and grounds for deletion were insufficient. So please restore. Motto: "If in doubt, be kind."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The name of our victim (and the first hint => AABBB) suggests that this puzzle has something to do with the [Bacon's cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher). The hard thing is to find groups of five letters which were used to encode the message.
>
>  The third hint adds IP addresses of the visited websites, which suggests that they were used to encode the message. The second hint (_icro_oft.co_ BFEF_C) tells us, we should transform the IP addresses from the decimal to hex representation:
>
>  `3270C49F`
>  `BFEFD5C5`
>  `36EF19C0`
>  `9765C122`
>  `0D214C9C`
>  `68103C25`
>  `58DD3E30`
>  `22C3021C`
>  `68C74088`
>  `D05E9964`
>  `976524C1`
>  `97658122`
>  `3F791E93`
>  `42D3A20C`
>  `97650043`
>  `0D521C3D`
>  `A1AAF814`
>  `9765C145`
>  `9765C18C`
>  `AB9FE496`
>  `5BC6AEC0`
>  `0D214CD9`
>  `D83AD16E`
>  `CFC84A37`
>
>  The second hint also implies, that we should ignore all digits in the hex representation which gives the following list:
>
>  `CF`
>  `BFEFDC`
>  `EFC`
>  `C`
>  `DCC`
>  `C`
>  `DDE`
>  `CC`
>  `C`
>  `DE`
>  `C`
>
>  `FE`
>  `DAC`
>
>  `DCD`
>  `AAAF`
>  `C`
>  `CC`
>  `ABFE`
>  `BCAEC`
>  `DCD`
>  `DADE`
>  `CFCA`
>
>  Let's join these letters in chronological order (bottom to top):
>
>  `CFCADADEDCDBCAECABFECCCAAAFDCD DACFE CDECCCDDECDCCCEFCBFEFDCCF`
>
>  The groups of letters are all divisible by 5, which means we are really close now. Using some trial and error we can map the six different letters to A and B usually used in the notation of Bacon's cipher (ABC => A, DEF => B):
>
>  `ABAABABBBABAAABAAABBAAAAAABBAB BAABB ABBAAABBBABAAABBAABBBBAAB`
>
>  Using the 26 letter variant of the cipher we can find out the name of the kidnapper:
>
>  `JORDAN T MORTZ`

Comment: Well reasoned! Part two coming soonish.

Answer (score 2):

A very partial answer that would have have been a comment, if it weren't too long:

The numbers on the piece of paper in the hint picture are very likely

> the first octets (the parts separated by dots) of the IP addresses of the sites.

They aren't all that well-defined, but here's what we get for all the sites:

> ```
>  twitch.tv                   52 or 50
>  microsoft.com               23, 104, 191, or 104
>  amazon.com                  54
>  gizmodo.com                151
>  kickstarter.com             13
>  discord.gg                 104
>  lastpass.com                88
>  instagram.com               52
>  open.spotify.com           104
>  southwest.com              208
>  imgur.com                  151
>  kotaku.com                 151
>  monster.com                 63 or 208
>  ebay.com                    66
>  xkcd.com                   151
>  msn.com                     13
>  walmart.com                161
>  puzzling.stackexchange.com 151
>  reddit.com                 151
>  bankofamerica.com          171
>  wikipedia.org               91
>  buzzfeed.com                13
>  gmail.com                  216
>  aol.com                    207
> ```

A quick analysis of that sequence got me absolutely nowhere.

Comment: (thinking face)

Comment: It's worth noting that the list appears to have the sites in alphabetical order

Comment: I hope there is nothing based on IP addresses - at least 2/3 of the sites from the list return more then 2 IP addresses, at least 7 return IPs with different first octet (even from different IP address classes) and some return different addresses in different regions of the world.

Comment: Alright, it looks like my grand scheme failed. I'll provide a list of the IP's he used in a hint soon.

Comment: @phroureo Probably everyone willing to try to solve this is waiting this list to continue :) Else idea is good to obscure numbers with domains, unfortunately it works only if you can guaranty that IPs never change and mapping is one-to-one always.

Comment: @kamenf OP delivered